# scoping in rails 3 with dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand why this doesn't work? Can anyone explain?

```
scope :upcoming, where(:start_time > Time.zone.now)
```

and another:

```
scope :happening_now, where(Time.zone.now.between?(:start_time, :end_time))
```

I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `<=>' for :end_time:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ernie/meta_where to the rescue, if you really want to write in that style.

Comment: I've ran into some bugs using meta_where and it certainly takes a performance hit because it hijacks your finders with tons more metaprogramming

Comment: I've looked at meta_where (which is probably why I thought this would work) but I'd like to stick with basic Ruby/SQL finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Proc to perform these kind of conditions.
Otherwise your query will become:

```
start_time > "time at which the server is started in production"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :upcoming, Proc.new { where(["start_time > ?", Time.zone.now])}
end
```

Comment: Can you explain that a little further? Without a Proc then the Time.zone.now is set on boot? Hmm… looks like I need to understand Procs better!

Answer (score 1):

Because what you're doing right now is comparing a symbol and a Time object

Try this:

`scope :upcoming, where("start_time > ?", Time.zone.now)`

If you want to pass a hash into #where, you need to specify both key and value. Example below:

`scope :example, where(:name => "chris")`

Comment: That worked really well. Thanks! I added one more for a bonus!